# Error "can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes" when generating website using python-pelican

Tags: python, pelican

I recently updated python-pelican on version 3.5.0. After that I did not work generation.The error is as follows:

```
ERROR: Could not process linux/ssh.md
  | can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
  |___
  | Traceback (most recent call last):
  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pelican/generators.py", line 502, in generate_context
  |     context_sender=self)
  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pelican/readers.py", line 492, in read_file
  |     context=context)
  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pelican/contents.py", line 136, in __init__
  |     if hasattr(self, 'date') and self.date > SafeDatetime.now():
  | TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

I've updated all the plugins, but to no avail.

Prior to the upgrade version was 3.3.0, and it worked fine.

Please help, how it can be solved?

(If there are errors, I'm sorry, did the translation from Google Translate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error. I managed to get around it by commenting the option `WITH_FUTURE_DATES = False` in my `publishconf.py`.

I didn't investigate any further, so I don't know the exact cause of the problem yet.